# reverseArray() codeademy using unshift()

Tags: javascript

```
// Using the .unshift() method
```

```
const reverseArray = arr => {
    let reversed = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        reversed.unshift(arr[i]);
    }
    return reversed
}
```

if we want to reverse order the last element will become the first.How can this method reverse the order when it starts at first index?

Comment: `unshift` always adds to the first index, that's how.

Comment: For each element (starting with the first and ending with the last), prepend it to (i.e. add to the *beginning* of) the `reversed` array. This produced an array with the elements in reverse order from the original.

Comment: unshift adds the element at the first index of array and in this case reversed array is getting updated with that element when looping with a for loop at the start of reversed array. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift and understand how for loop works :)

Comment: ```reversedArray = [...originalArray].reverse()``` does the job too

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp#:%7E:text=The%20unshift()%20method%20adds,an%20array%2C%20use%20push()%20.):

> The unshift() method adds new items to the beginning of an array, and
> returns the new length

So in each iteration you are adding item to the beginning of an array and when iteration is done you have reversed array.

Comment: @misssn Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

"array.unshift()" is use to push items into array, you need to use "array.reverse()" to reverse the array.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.unshift(4, 5);
console.log(arr);
// reverse
arr.reverse(arr, "this is unshift");
console.log(arr, "this is reverse");

// output: arr [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I pretty sure they introduce `reverse` also in Codecademy, the question is, how `unshift` can reverse an array.

Comment: you mean your function will return reverse array right?

Comment: It's no my function, but yes, OP's function returns a reversed array, and they want to know how it works, not an alternative to their function.